# NetBeans 8.1 Activation Failure

Tags: java, netbeans, ubuntu-14.04, netbeans-8.1

I am trying to install NetBeans 8.1 on my Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS. When I try to create a new project, it shows an error, saying that "not all requested modules can be enabled". I tried activating it from the plugins, but to no avail.

Why is this happening, and what can I do to resolve it?

[image: Check the screenshot here]

Comment: Which java version you are using? `java -version`

Comment: @SubOptimal 1.7.0_85

Comment: @kylas What kind of project you tried to create?

Comment: @WillShackleford As the installation path is `/home/khlim/netbeans-8.1` I would assume it was not installed from a Ubuntu repository.

Comment: its fine now. I have changed the path in the config file.

Comment: Maybe you tried to run Netbeans with an JRE not a JDK (see https://forums.netbeans.org/post-167346.html)

Answer (score 43):

I had the same problem with NetBeans 8.1 on Linux Mint 17.2 and I found the solution (during install a have chosen wrong JDK directory).

If a compatible JDK installation cannot be found, you might need to manually add a path to the JDK installation directory by doing the following:

1. Open the **netbeans.conf** file located in the **netbeans/etc** directory in a text editor.
2. Enter the location of a compatible JDK installation for the netbeans_jdkhome option. The default location in Windows is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67 or similar.
   **In my case: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/**
3. Save the netbeans.conf file and run the executable file in the netbeans/bin directory.

https://netbeans.org/community/releases/81/install.html#install_zip

Comment: Yes, this fixed the problem on Ubuntu for me too.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 16

Comment: If someone experiences this issue with openSUSE, the location that should be used for `netbeans_jdkhome` is usually `/usr/lib64/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0`, but bear in mind that this is true for **java-1_8_0-openjdk**. For java-1_7_0-openjdk and java-9-openjdk you would need to tweak the path accordingly.

Answer (score 18):

Just in case, I solved this just by commenting out the following line;

```
netbeans_jdkhome="/usr"
```

To

```
#netbeans_jdkhome="/usr"
```

## Edit:

The directory of the above code is inside the file ***~/netbeans-8.1/etc/netbeans***

Comment: After installing JDK 8, your solution resolved my issue.

Comment: To clarify, this line was located in ~/netbeans-8.1/etc/netbeans.conf for my installation.

Comment: For Netbeans 8.2 and actual Debian or Ubuntu i had to be more precise and declase netbeans_jdkhome=" /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle" . This worked for me

Comment: As mentioned by @zkjellberg . The line was located in ~/netbeans-8.1/etc/netbeans.conf. I forgot to put it together

Comment: fixing JAVA_HOME should fix this as well

Answer (score 0):

1) uninstall Netbeans & download JDK 8 http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html from Here

2) Extract JDK to /home/username/

3) Download Netbeans https://netbeans.org/downloads/

4) Install Netbeans from terminal follow [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/03/install-netbeans-ide-8-0-in-ubuntu-14-0413-1012-04/) tutorial

5) Installation asks jdk location then browse to /home/username/jdk1.8.0_91

problem solved.....

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact issues,what I have done is :-1

1. uninstall net-beans,
   2.I already have Oracle Java 8 installed.
   3.install net-beans back and make sure to select Oracle Java 8 jdk during the installation .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that right JDK directory chosen in the installation wizard if you not sure you can change it from `C:\Program Files\NetBeans {netbeans version}\etc` you will see a file which is `netbeans.conf` edit it(I am using Notepad++ for that) At the bottom of the file, you will see a line `netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\{jdk directory you want}"` make sure it is valid JDK and it is JDK, not JRE