# Cannot create new project on netbean debian 8.1, not all requested modules can be enabled

Tags: java, netbeans

I install latest netbean from netbean.org on debian 64bit.
I'm not use openjdk, I use jdk from oracle.

when I create new project something when wrong.

[image: Error on here]

where's the fault?
How to make it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that my question is looks like this question: [NetBeans 8.1 Activation Failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33868896/netbeans-8-1-activation-failure)

Open the netbeans.conf file located in the netbeans/etc directory.
And then change a jdkhome.
It's work.